# Convert list of value related with another list of id to matrices

Tags: python, list, matrix

I have data with list of id

```
a = [52, 10, 31] 
b = [20, 43] 
c = [43, 20, 10, 52]
```

and the score of id like above

```
a = [0.89, 0.75, 0.6]
b = [0.9, 0.86]
c = [0.98, 0.78, 0.65, 0.63]
```

I want to convert to matrices 3(a, b, c) x 5(union of id and sort id ascending) like this

```
matrices = [[0.75  0     0.6   0     0.89]
            [0     0.9   0     0.86  0   ]
            [0.65  0.78  0     0.98  0.63]]
```

Anyone can solve this? Thanks

Comment: Python has only `list` for showing matrices. How these `0`s fit in output?

Comment: Now that you replaced your existing requirements with the new one, none of the existing answers makes any sense anymore (and your question neither). Please _explain_ why e.g. 0.9 should go to that specific position if the index is 20! Where do the 0s come from now?

Comment: Hi @tobias_k 0.9 is score for id 20 not index 20

Comment: Yes, that's clear, but why does it go that THAT position of the matrix? How do you determine which positions get a number from the lists and which get a zero?

Comment: I think now I got what you want. See my update. You really should have explained that better, though.

Comment: @tobias_k great code! but why result `matrix[1]` is [`0, 0.9, 0, 0, 0]` not `[0, 0.9, 0, 0.86, 0]`

Comment: @NovanDwiAtmaja There was a typo in your code. `0,86` should be `0.86`.

Comment: @tobias_k Lol. I missed that. Thank a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With plain Python lists, you could try something like the following:

```
indices = [[1, 3, 5], [2, 4], [1, 2, 4, 5]]
scores = [[0.75, 0.6, 0.89], [0.9, 0.86], [0.65, 0.78, 0.98, 0.63]]
matrix = [[0] * 5 for _ in range(3)]

for i, (ind, scr) in enumerate(zip(indices, scores)):
    for k, s in zip(ind, scr):
        matrix[i][k-1] = s

print(matrix)
# [[0.75, 0, 0.6, 0, 0.89], [0, 0.9, 0, 0.86, 0], [0.65, 0.78, 0, 0.98, 0.63]]
```

Or as a horrible one-liner:

```
>>> [[next(scr) if i+1 in ind else 0 for i in range(5)]
...  for ind, scr in ((set(ind), iter(scr)) for ind, scr in zip(indices, scores))]
...
[[0.75, 0, 0.6, 0, 0.89],
 [0, 0.9, 0, 0.86, 0],
 [0.65, 0.78, 0, 0.98, 0.63]]
```

---

Update: If the ids are not the indices, you have to re-map them first, then, you can continue with the first approach.

```
ids = [52, 10, 31], [20, 43], [43, 20, 10, 52]
scores = [0.89, 0.75, 0.6], [0.9, 0.86],  [0.98, 0.78, 0.65, 0.63]

d = {x: i+1 for i, x in enumerate(sorted(set.union(*map(set, ids))))}
# {52: 5, 10: 1, 43: 4, 20: 2, 31: 3}    

matrix = [[0] * max(d.values()) for _ in range(len(ids))]
for i, (ind, scr) in enumerate(zip(ids, scores)):
    for k, s in zip(ind, scr):
        matrix[i][d[k]-1] = s
print(matrix)
# [[0.75, 0, 0.6, 0, 0.89], [0, 0.9, 0, 0.86, 0], [0.65, 0.78, 0, 0.98, 0.63]]
```

Comment: Thanks @tobias_k but how to handle when the id is random? example
`indices = [[10, 31, 52], [20, 43], [10, 20, 43, 52]]`

Comment: The matrices have same large 3 x 5 but the id list changed

Comment: @NovanDwiAtmaja If the matrix is still 3x5, how is there supposed to be a value at index 20 or 52? What should be the result in that case?

Comment: Same result but list of id is `a = [10, 31, 52]
b = [20, 43]
c = [10, 20, 43, 52]` if i use your loop i get error message `matrix[i][k-1] = s
IndexError: list assignment index out of range`

Comment: Yes, I have 3 person with id person `[a, b, c]` and 5 test with id test `[10, 20, 31, 43, 52]` but not every people have all test score (doing test), so i want create matrix of person and test with the score value

Comment: @NovanDwiAtmaja So much is clear, but how should the result look then? Please update your question with a second example.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you fill the `0`s beforehand:
Using something like:

```
a = [1, 3, 5]

b1 = [x for x in range(a[0], a[-1] + 1)]
a = set(a)

missing_elem = list(a ^ set(b1))
print((missing_elem))
```

OUTPUT:

```
[2,4]
```

and then append those to the original list `a`

Now:

```
import numpy as np

a = [0.75, 0, 0.6, 0, 0.89]
b = [0, 0.9, 0, 0.86, 0]
c = [0.65, 0.78, 0, 0.98, 0.63]

print(np.column_stack((a,b,c)))
```

OUTPUT:

```
[[0.75 0.   0.65]
 [0.   0.9  0.78]
 [0.6  0.   0.  ]
 [0.   0.86 0.98]
 [0.89 0.   0.63]]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a dirty code, but you'll get the results.

```
a_id = [1, 3, 5]
b_id = [2, 4]
c_id = [1, 2, 4, 5]

a_score = [0.75, 0.6, 0.89]
b_score = [0.9, 0.86]
c_score = [0.65, 0.78, 0.98, 0.63]

N, M = 3, 5
matrices = []

for i in range(N):
    matrices.append([0 for j in range(M)])

for i in range(N):
    for j in range(M):
        try:
            if i == 0:
                matrices[i][a_id[j]-1] = a_score[j]
            elif i == 1:
                matrices[i][b_id[j]-1] = b_score[j]
            else:
                matrices[i][c_id[j]-1] = c_score[j]
        except:
            pass

print(matrices)
```

How about this if there are many ids and scores?

```
list_id = []
list_score = []

list_id.extend((a_id, b_id, c_id))
list_score.extend((a_score, b_score, c_score))


N, M = len(list_score), max(map(max, list_id))
matrices = []

for i in range(N):
    matrices.append([0 for j in range(M)])

for i in range(N):
    for j in range(M):
        try:
            matrices[i][list_id[i][j] - 1] = list_score[i][j]
        except IndexError:
            pass
```

Comment: thanks @tigermeal but i have many id and many score, i cannot explain if else as long as i have id_score list

Comment: @NovanDwiAtmaja I added code that can handle a lot of ids.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to create a sparse matrix, you may try [`coo_matrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.coo_matrix) from [`scipy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/index.html)

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix

data_a = [0.75, 0.6, 0.89]
data_b = [0.9, 0.86]
data_c = [0.65, 0.78, 0.98, 0.63]
id_a = [1, 3, 5]
id_b = [2, 4]
id_c = [1, 2, 4, 5]

sp_a = coo_matrix((data_a, ([0] * len(data_a), [x - 1 for x in id_a])), shape=(1, 5)).toarray()
sp_b = coo_matrix((data_b, ([0] * len(data_b), [x - 1 for x in id_b])), shape=(1, 5)).toarray()
sp_c = coo_matrix((data_c, ([0] * len(data_c), [x - 1 for x in id_c])), shape=(1, 5)).toarray()

matrices = np.vstack([sp_a, sp_b, sp_c])

print(matrices)
# >>> matrices
# array([[0.75, 0.  , 0.6 , 0.  , 0.89],
#        [0.  , 0.9 , 0.  , 0.86, 0.  ],
#        [0.65, 0.78, 0.  , 0.98, 0.63]])
```